# Binary file is not saving if length of string is not same

Tags: java, binaryfiles

I am trying to save text and int value in a binary file but it is not working as expected.

This is my code.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first name of doctor : ");
        String fn=input.next();
        System.out.println("enter middle name of doctor : ");
        String mn=input.next();
        FileOutputStream os=new FileOutputStream("Doctorsdata.txt");
        DataOutputStream file=new DataOutputStream(os);

        file.writeUTF(fn.trim());
        file.writeUTF(mn.trim());

        FileInputStream osb=new FileInputStream("Doctorsdata.txt");
        DataInputStream osa=new DataInputStream(osb);
        System.out.println("a "+osa.readUTF());
        System.out.println("b "+osa.readUTF());
        file.close();
}
}
```

This is my input

```
fn                        mn                         Output
abc                       def                         ̀a扡c搃晥
abc                       defg                         abc defg
```

If i write fn and mn as of same length it will work and if they are of not same length it will not work like above. Also if I have a 3rd variable of type byte and i will write like `file.writeByte(age);` in first input's case it will not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use `writeUTF()` to write the string but uses `readByte()` to read it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should show that the incorrect data is read from the file.

Comment: Updated. **It should show that the incorrect data is read from the file.** It is displaying correct data but in file it should not show data in human readable form.

Comment: The data is written and read correctly using the code you have. But if you want to save it in a different format inside the file you have to change the content before saving (and change it back when reading). You can use encryption for that if people shouldn't be able to "look" into the file. So, what is the actual question/problem you have?

Comment: What do you mean by "in file it should not show data in human readable form" ?

Comment: I've just tried the code above = it works for me as you expect. MacOs, adoptopenjdk-11.

Comment: what's your output in file?

Comment: "in file it should not show data in human readable form" means data like a扡c搃晥

Comment: @AbdullahBadar The file include the content you wrote via `writeUTF()` as well as some control bytes declaring the types and values inside the file as defined/used by the `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` classes.

Comment: The content of the file you write is dictated by `writeUTF`. Details aside (you can check them out by looking at the documentation), your implementation does not control the format of contents of the file - only of the data written to and read from it.

Comment: @DavidSoroko so how can we handle the format?

Comment: You need to think carefully about what you are trying to achieve. It looks like your code is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. It sounds like you are unhappy with the resulting file contents, it is not clear why you are unhappy. You can start by changing the title of this post to reflect the issue you are actually facing.

Comment: @ David Soroko basically i want the data which is being stored in the file to be in binary form but unfortunetly that is not happening